# has uncovered http methods for path: /

Tags: xml, web, jetty

2021-03-02 18:52:52 [main] WARN  o.e.jetty.security.SecurityHandler - ServletContext@o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@xxx{ROOT,/,file:///home/y/libexec/webapps/ROOT/,STARTING}{/home/y/libexec/webapps/ROOT} has uncovered http methods for path: /

and {WEB-INF,/WEB-INF,file:///home/y/libexec/webapps/WEB-INF/,STARTING}{/home/y/libexec/webapps/WEB-INF} has uncovered http methods for path: /

I added

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Disable TRACE</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Enable everything but TRACE</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <http-method-omission>TRACE</http-method-omission>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

in web.xml file. But these two still exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a version of Jetty with a bug related to merging of RoleInfo on the Constraints.

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/5909

The easiest solution is to upgrade your version of Jetty to at least ...

- 9.4.38.v20210224 (or newer)
- 10.0.1 (or newer)
- 11.0.1 (or newer)